# Как последовательно передать данные с формы в php через ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Имеется два файла:

1) index.html

```
<form id="myForm">
<textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="field1"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myForm').submit(function(){
                var str = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: str,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#content").html(html);
                   }
                });
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
```

2) test.php

```
<?php 
$field1 = $_POST['field1'];
echo "Приветствую, <b>".$field1."</b>!<br>";
echo "Time: " . date("H:i:s") . "<br/>" . "\n";
sleep(5);
echo "Done";
?>
```

Входные данные:

```
 Маша
 Даша
 Петя
 Саша
```

Данные идут списком, разделены \r\n.

Как последовательно передать данные, используя ajax, в php файл, чтобы на выходе получилось:

```
Приветствую, Маша
Time: 10:06:00
ok
Приветствую, Даша
Time: 10:06:05
ok
Приветствую, Петя
Time: 10:06:10
ok
Приветствую, Саша
Time: 10:06:15
ok
```

Данные должны появляться на странице постепенно, в данном случае через 5 секунд, возможно, получая призыв в последующему действию после получения     echo "ok";
Предполагаю, что сначала, из данных нужно получить массив в js, разделителем при котором будет \n\r, постепенно скармливать php, предварительно открыв сессию.

**Примечание:** вариант с получением массива в php, его последующим разложением и отправкой в echo не подходит, так как при большом объеме входящих данных будет высокая нагрузка, что увеличит ожидание и может вызвать ошибку, да и о постепенной выдачи информации в html речи быть не может.

Answer (score 1):

изначально все данные из формы сохраняй в базу/файл, дальше ajax запрашивай сервер каждые 5 секунд, по приходу данных добавляй их на страницу, сервер в свою очередь пусть отдает по одной записи, в конце отдавай флаг что данные закончились